# Listen to Log.Fatal(...) messages

Tags: c#, log4net

I have an application with lots of logging of all levels. I wish to add some custom behavior to the `Log.Fatal` calls. Is that possible to do without building a custom Appender?

I tried this:

```
    log4net.Util.LogLog.LogReceived += LogLog_LogReceived;        

    private void LogLog_LogReceived(object source, LogReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

But `LogReceived` doesn't seem to be fired. It's perhaps not intended to be used this way. Not sure.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realized my question is probably doable (some way), but not at all wise. Creating a custom appender is so easy that it would make anything related to my question silly to demand from the logging framework. Sorry that I asked explicitly how to do that WITHOUT appender. It's stupid.

I ended up adding this to my assembly:

```
namespace MyAssembly
{
    public class MyAppenderClass: AppenderSkeleton
    {
        protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
        {
            // something, something, dark side.
        }
    }  
}
```

and adding this piece of config:

```xml
<root>
  <!-- Set the log level for the entire application here -->
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="MyAppender" />
</root>    

<appender name="MyAppender" type="MyAssembly.MyAppenderClass">
  <!-- the threshold is to make sure it starts logging FATAL and up (so only FATAL really) -->
  <threshold value="FATAL" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="[%date - %message%newline%exception" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

And that's it. Lovely log4net.

Comment: Would be nice if one could do this without an appender, or maybe add the appender with code. I'm using 3rdparty components that does not at all give any progress info, but it logs what it is doing, so that is my only way of getting any sort of progress information for now.